# JS How to access current value from a created popup dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the selected option (value) of the dropdown menu in a variable but I'm having trouble with getting it stored because I'm getting errors about it not existing. I understand that html can have order issues but because the popup's html elements are all written in a JS file's function I'm not sure how to circumvent that.

[image: picture of popup]

Essentially, I'm trying to use something like this at a specific point to save the selected option.

`var chosenGender = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;`

This gives me a `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` which, I believe means that it can't find my mySelect element which agrees with all the other tests I've run. This happens even when I check for an element I created and id'ed immediately before leading me to believe that there's just something I'm missing here. How would I go about detecting completely new html elements that were inserted only with js?

Edits for additional clarification: I've tried  `document.getElementById("mySelect").value;` immediately after I append the following to the divclass I'm creating. All this below is part of a larger function with a lot more html formatting that I've tried to cut down to the important info but I might have cut something important.

```
var genderArray = ["Choose One","Masculine","Feminine","Neuter","Ambiguous","Adjective"];

var pickGender = document.createElement("div");
pickGender.setAttribute("id","pickGender");

//Create and append select list
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
selectList.setAttribute("class", "popup");  
pickGender.appendChild(selectList);

for (var i = 0; i < genderArray.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", genderArray[i]);
    option.text = genderArray[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}

content.appendChild(heading);
content.appendChild(pickGender);
document.body.appendChild(hostDiv); 

if (document.getElementById("mySelect")){
    console.log("We found it");
} else {
    console.log("Can't find mySelect");
}
```

Comment: when do you `document.getElementById("mySelect")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the change event that is fired when the user makes a selection from your list. Also, the HTML must be written correctly to include the `value=` attribute.

```js
document.querySelector("#pet-select").addEventListener("change",function(e){
  console.log(e.target.value);
})
```

```html
<label for="pet-select">Choose a pet:</label>

<select name="pets" id="pet-select">
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
  <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
  <option value="spider">Spider</option>
  <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
</select>
```